# React native app sending push notification while device is offline

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification, expo

I'm about to develop an app similar to a birthday reminder and I plan to use firebase for push notifications but what makes me second question my choice is whether users will be able to receive a birthday notification if they are offline(not connected to internet for the whole birthday day). I know firebase has some offline persistence support but I'm not sure if this includes push notifications support. Are there any options to achieve that with firebase or with any other tool compatible with react native?

Answer (score 1):

If the device is not connected to the internet, it is going to be impossible to deliver messages to it through Firebase Cloud Messaging or other internet protocols.

The common way to deal with such a scenario is to **deliver** the message to the device when the user *does* have an internet connection, and then only **display** it once it's the right time. By sending a [data-only message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages) through FCM, your application code controls exactly what happens with the message data.

Comment: Deliver the messages when device is connected and display them when its right time might be an option, I just investigated the local push notifications and I'm wondering whether I will be able to schedule N local push notification for after an year, is that possible ?

Comment: I don't think scheduling is involved. On Android you'd run a background service to do this, and I assume iOS has something similar.

Answer (score 0):

There are essentially two types of notifications: in app messaging and cloud messaging. Both are offered by Firebase: In App Messaging and FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging).

The details you've given about your app is a little bit vague but if you're asking for push notifications, then FCM does the job. FCM will send notification when the app is on background or killed (exited out). When you say device is offline I'm assuming you mean when the user isn't using the phone. Yes, the notification will still come.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging

Comment: Sorry,  I agree info is not enough, I updated my question - what I mean is if the user is not connected to internet for the whole birthday day.